# Query Registry in WIX Installer

Tags: .net, windows, wix

Installed `.Net` windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.6.exe after [windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.4.exe](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-desktop-6.0.6-windows-x64-installer)
My custom installer needs to check if a `Version >= 6.0.4` is installed if the installed Version is compatible with my executable. Which would require that the major version did not change. e.g. 6.0.5, 6.0.6.
Image of Registry Pat:

[image: Image of Registry Path]

The .net installer deletes the registry entry for 6.0.4 and creates a new DWORD named `6.0.6` in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedfx\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App`.
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to query this in the WIX installer. I would prefer to do it without a CustomAction.

Install condition was the Value of the DWORD `Version` stored in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedf`.

Comment: 32bit, 64bit or either?  And are you wanting to do this in the MSI and/or EXE bootstrapper?

Comment: 64bit. The installer is an exe bootsrapper

Comment: I have now fixed the problem by handling the exit code of the installer.

`<ExitCode Value="1638" Behavior="success" />`